# in gridview how to add the textbox when user click on link button?

Tags: asp.net

I have gridview which contain four column ID,Name,Address and Ph_No.
In gridview, one column for link button ID=Edit.
When user click on the link "Edit" then textbox will be display in gridview control.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `EditIndex` property of `GridView`.

```
GridView1.EditIndex=1;
//code to rebind the GridView
```

Or handle RowEditing event of GridView with following code

```
GridView1.EditIndex=e.NewEditIndex;
//code to rebind the GridView
```